# How to rollback to the beginning in pl/sql when there is no savepoint?

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I made some changes to database which is leading my page to crash. I want to undo the changes. But rollback works only upto last commit, and I need to roll it back about 6 commmits or say, to the start of the day and I didn't manually define any save points.

How can I do it?

Comment: Questions on professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com/).

Comment: You can't rollback beyond a commit, unless you have manually stored the commands to rollback the data yourself. When you tell Oracle to commit, you're telling it to write the changes into the database to make them permanent. A rollback will only ever undo uncommitted changes - ie. ones that haven't been made permanent yet. Sounds like your code is either committing too frequently or you need to manually undo the changes, depending on what you're doing (e.g. you might be testing across several transactions, rather than a single one that has too many commits).

Comment: @Boneist what happens if i kill the session,does it make the commits I gave  void?

Comment: @sphinx9 no; once you have committed, the data is in the database. It's a little bit like making a ceramic pot - up until you fire the pot, you can reshape the clay. Once the pot has been fired, the changes are permanent, so you can't turn it back into clay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> " I need to roll it back about 6 commmits or say, to the start of the day and I didn't manually define any save points."

You cannot do this. Issuing a COMMIT finalizes the transaction and makes the outcome visible to other sessions. That means other users will base their activity on the changes you have committed. Allowing you to rollback those changes after that point would inject horrible corruption into the database.

Issuing a SAVEPOINT wouldn't have changed this, because a savepoint is simply a way of breaking up **a single transaction** into a number of reversible chunks. But once the commit happens the savepoints are wiped.

Your only option is to use the Flashback technology. Provided your DBA has configured the database with enough storage you should be able to recover the state of the database to a particular point in time. You can then decide how to proceed; exactly what you can choose to do rather depends on the nature of the changes you're looking to reverse. Anyway, [find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#g1026131).